# Printing a Class

Tags: python, class, output

Hi I'm trying to print 4 band members details using a class, however I'm only able to print one, ill give samples to give you an understanding below, this is my whole code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, _firstname, _surname, d, m, y):
        self._firstname = _firstname
        self._surname = _surname
        self.d = d
        self.m = m
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, john._surname, john.d, john.m, john.y)
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(paul._firstname, paul._surname,     paul.d, paul.m, paul.y)
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(george._firstname,     george._surname, george.d, george.m, george.y)
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(ringo._firstname, ringo._surname,     ringo.d, ringo.m, ringo.y)

john = Person('John','Lennon','8th','October','1940')
paul = Person('Paul','McCartney','18th','June','1942')
george = Person('George','Harrison','25th','February','1943')
ringo = Person('Ringo','Starr','7th','July','1940')


john._firstname = 'John'
john._surname = 'Lennon'
john.d = '8th'
john.m = 'October'
john.y = '1940'


paul._firstname = 'Paul'
paul._surname = 'McCartney'
paul._d = '18th'
paul._m = 'June'
paul._y = '1942'

george._firstname = 'George'
george._surname = 'Harrison'
george._d = '25th'
george._m = 'February'
george._y = '1943'

ringo._firstname = 'Ringo'
ringo._surname = 'Starr'
ringo._d = '7th'
ringo._m = 'July'
ringo._y = '1940'

print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, john._surname, john.d, john.m, john.y))
print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(paul._firstname, paul._surname, paul.d,     paul.m, paul.y))
print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(george._firstname, george._surname,         george.d, george.m, george.y))
print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(ringo._firstname, ringo._surname,     ringo.d,     ringo.m, ringo.y))
```

I receive, the correct output, which is this:

```
John Lennon
8th October 1940
Paul McCartney 
18th June 1942
George Harrison 
25th February 1943
Ringo Starr 
7th July 1940
```

I want to be able to type:

```
print(john)
print(george)
print(paul)
print(ringo)
```

To get the same output, however when i type this and remove the bottom 4 print lines, i get this

```
John Lennon 
8th October 1940
John Lennon 
8th October 1940
John Lennon 
8th October 1940
John Lennon 
8th October 1940
```

My understanding up until now is that the `__repr__(self)` can only read one line of code, which would be `john`, but that's where my knowledge stops.

ANY help is more than appreciated! if you need more info please ask, I'm quite new to this as I'm in my first year at university so I appreciate your patience and help!:)

Comment: Your `__repr__` function is a bit freakish. Use `self` instead of `john` for example, and only return one string.

Comment: Most of that code is unnecessary; the purpose of passing arguments when you create an object is so that you don't subsequently need to write things like `john._firstname = "John"`; `__init__` has already been called and done that for you.

Comment: Also, you really should be defining `__str__`, not `__repr__`. Both return string representations of an object, but have different use cases.

Comment: In Python, a member whose name starts with an underscore is considered as private (it is not listed by `help`). Therefore, you should refrain yourself from directly accessing/setting those. If you want to do so, then those members should not be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `return` command will simply exit the function, so having multiple `return` commands at the same level would never work in Python.

The issue with your code is that you should be using the key word `self` within your `__repr__` definition, that way you can access it with all four instances that you create with

```
john = Person('John','Lennon','8th','October','1940')
paul = Person('Paul','McCartney','18th','June','1942')
george = Person('George','Harrison','25th','February','1943')
ringo = Person('Ringo','Starr','7th','July','1940')
```

Those creations of instances of the class `Person` will also automatically store all the information that you enter, so no need to specify by hand values for `john._firstname` etc.

**To give a clear answer:**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, _firstname, _surname, d, m, y):
        self._firstname = _firstname
        self._surname = _surname
        self.d = d
        self.m = m
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(self._firstname,
                                         self._surname,
                                         self.d,
                                         self.m,
                                         self..y)

john = Person('John','Lennon','8th','October','1940')
paul = Person('Paul','McCartney','18th','June','1942')
george = Person('George','Harrison','25th','February','1943')
ringo = Person('Ringo','Starr','7th','July','1940')

print(john)
print(paul)
print(george)
print(ringo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__repr__` talks about class instances like `john`. It needs to be written to cater for *any* instance of `Person`.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(self._firstname, self._surname, self.d, self.m, self.y)
```

Answer (score -1):

You leave a function with a `return`-statement. Following lines are ignored.
Within a method when accessing the attributes you only use placeholders for the objects itself. Use `self` instead of real names of objects.

```
def __repr__(self): 
  return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(
    self._firstname, self._surname, self.d, self.m, self.y)
```